# R: calculating the time spent by N individuals within each of M time intervals

Tags: r

There are four time intervals

```
[0, 3), [3, 10), [10, 12), and [12, Inf)
```

and three subjects for whom we have survival times

```
10.3, 0.7, 12.2
```

I would like to construct a matrix with three rows (one for each individual) and four column (one for each time interval) that contains the time spent by each individual within each time interval.

For this particular example, we have

```
  3.0  7  0.3  0.0
  0.7  0  0.0  0.0
  3.0  7  2.0  0.2
```

Can you help me to obtain this in `R`? The idea is to apply this for N much larger than 3.

---

My attempt:

```
breaks <- c(0, 3, 10, 12, Inf) # interval break points
M <- length(breaks) - 1        # number of intervals
time <- c(10.3, 0.7, 12.2)     # observed survival times
N <- length(time)              # number of subjects

timeSpent <- matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=M) 
for(m in 1:M)
{
  ind <- which(breaks[m + 1] - time > 0)
  timeSpent[ind, m] <- time[ind] - breaks[m]
  timeSpent[-ind, m] <- breaks[m + 1] - breaks[m]
}
timeSpent <- replace(x=timeSpent, list=timeSpent < 0, values=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
breaks <- c(0, 3, 10, 12, Inf)
time <- c(10.3, 0.7, 12.2)
timeSpent  <- sapply(time, function(x) {
  int <- max(which(x>breaks))
  res <- diff(breaks)
  res[int:length(res)] <- 0
  res[int] <- x-breaks[int]
  res
                                 })

t(timeSpent)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  3.0    7  0.3  0.0
#[2,]  0.7    0  0.0  0.0
#[3,]  3.0    7  2.0  0.2
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice proposal (+1). However, my tests show that it is pretty slow as N grows. I will edit my post to make it clear that I would like to apply this for N larger than 3.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't loop and should be faster. However, a potential problem could be memory demand.

```
tmp <- t(outer(time, breaks, ">"))
res <- tmp * breaks
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res <- diff(res)

res[diff(tmp)==-1] <- time+res[diff(tmp)==-1]
t(res)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  3.0    7  0.3  0.0
#[2,]  0.7    0  0.0  0.0
#[3,]  3.0    7  2.0  0.2
```